# Transparent hover working on JSFiddle but not on website

Tags: html, css

I decided to make a JSFiddle to show you guys what was wrong but it ended up working, I used the exact same code but it still has an opacity of 1 when hovered on the website. I've uploaded what I have so far of my website to show what I mean. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98NsN/) and the html code.

```
<div class="wide-col gjw">
    <div class="portfolio-info">
        <p class="portfolio-title">GJW Website v1.0</p>
        <p class="portfolio-desc">The first version of my portfolio website</p>
        <a class="portfolio-button" href="#">View Brief</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JSFiddle does what I want it to do by having a transparent hover colour. Now when I have the same code on my website the opacity is full as shown [here](http://garethjweaver.com/gjw/)

I don't understand why it won't do it on my website but on the fiddle? I don't think there is any other code that hinders it...

Cheers in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `opacity` specified in `.gjw:hover .portfolio-info` is getting overridden by some scripts in your website.

[image]

[image]

either remove/correct the script or apply `!important` keyword to prevent this.

```
.gjw:hover .portfolio-info {
   opacity: 0.9 !important;
   ...
 }
```

*The web console and  it's inspect element feature are your friends…*

Comment: Thanks but there was no where in my script that said opacity:1; which is weird even though it says opacity:1; in the inspect element

Comment: @Gereth Chrome inspector shows which file and line number to look in just next to the selector.

Comment: Just taking a quick look on your webpage you see immediately an inline `<script></script>` with said code. (right before the end of body)